# Gathering the confidence with JAVACV program

Tags: opencv, javacv, face-recognition, confidence-interval

Trying to figure out a way to gather the confidence level when it actually does the face recognizing on the target image. I have searched through a few examples but haven't found anything I can see how to implement.  All help appreciated, thanks guys.

```
public static void facecompare() {
    String trainingDir = "C:/TrainingDirectory";     //training directory
    IplImage testImage = cvLoadImage("C:/TargetImages/boland_straight_happy_open_4.pgm"); //the target image

    File root = new File(trainingDir);

    FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pgm");
        }
    };

    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img;
    IplImage grayImg;

    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        img = cvLoadImage(image.getAbsolutePath());

        label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);

        grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.put(counter, grayImg);

        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }

    IplImage greyTestImage = IplImage.create(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);



    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer();

    faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

    cvCvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);

    System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another *predict* method that returns the confidence:

```
// pointer-like output parameters
// only the first element of these arrays will be changed
int[] plabel = new int[1];
double[] pconfidence = new double[1];

faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage, plabel, pconfidence);

int predictedLabel = plabel[0];
double confidence = pconfidence[0];
```

Comment: I'd expect that such method returns all confidence values for all images in the training set. But, at least for me, it gives only the confidence value for the predicted image. It's normal?